# Enormous SEs in zero-inflated negative binomial regression

Tags: standard-error, count-data, zero-inflation, overdispersion

I have overdispersed count data where the outcome is events (occurrence of a rare disease) and the covariate of interest is season. The unit of analysis is the number of events occurring in a country-season combination. We have 16 countries and 4 seasons repeated across each country, thus 64 data points:

[image]

Since I was suspicious that there may also be an excess of zeroes, I ran several different regression models for comparison:

**Negative binomial**
[image]

**Zero-inflated Poisson (ZIP)**
[image]

**Negative binomial hurdle (NBH)**
[image]

**Zero-inflated negative binomial (ZINB)**
[image]

The models yield similar results, except for one thing. **The SEs of ZINB's zero model are enormous.** The other three models have reasonable SEs. There is only one covariate (season) except for the offset term, so no collinearity. The residuals are asymmetric judging by the five-number summary in the output, but that's true for several of the models and it makes sense intuitively.

What could be causing this?

**EDIT #1**
There doesn't seem to be perfect separation in the binomial part of the model.

[image]

**EDIT #2**
Here are some Pearson residual plots. Definitely not normal, and perhaps heteroscedastic (but the latter, at least, is to be expected). However, I really have no idea what residuals from a ZINB model "should" look like if the model fits.

[image]

Comment: As the large SEs are in the binomial part of the model, I check if separation might be an issue - i.e. you can perfectly predict the response at some value of the predictor. Have you plotted the data as binary values (0,1) as a function of the seasons?

Comment: Edited in response

Answer (score 5):

(Hope this is an appropriate way to answer my own question; maybe this should be a comment?)

I figured out the problem thanks in part to [a fantastic answer on count regression diagnostics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70558/diagnostic-plots-for-count-regression). The offset was the culprit causing the huge SEs, and the residuals and other goodness-of-fit diagnostics were accordingly strange. The offset term may have been a problem because one of the countries (China) had a huge population but comparatively few cases.

For comparison, here is the ZINB without the offset:

[image]

Hope this helps anyone else experiencing similar problems.